# minimum Age validation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to validation a users information like date of birth for that i have used following line of statement in validation, But how do i make it dynamic so users minimum age could be 13. below that can't register?

```
  return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'date_of_birth' =>'required|date|before:2011-06-08',
        ]);
```

Comment: Is it validating when you write the date like this `2011-06-08`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation, you should be able to use any valid string that works with the strtotime() function. In this case strtotime('13 years ago') is a valid descriptor for the dynamic date you are after. Hence, the following should work:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    'date_of_birth' =>'required|date|before:13 years ago',
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Carbon for that like this :

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'date_of_birth' =>'required|date|before:'.Carbon::now()->subYears(13),
    ]);
```

Ps : Don't forget to add the the import `use Carbon\Carbon;`.

Answer (score 1):

To check user's age as minimum 13 years use [after](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-after) rule. Change rule for `date_of_birth` to

```
'date_of_birth' =>'required|date|after:13 years',
```

`before` will not work as it is opposite of `after`